# can anyone tell me how val[i*c+j] is working?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int* val;
    int r,c;
    val = new int[r*c];
    cout<<"Enter Rows:";
    cin>>r;
    cout<<"Enter cols :";
    cin>>c; 
    for(int i= 0 ;i<r ;i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<c; j++)
        {
            cin>>val[i*c+j]; 
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<r ;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0 ;j<c;j++)
        {
            cout<<val[i*c+j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    delete []val;
    return 0;

}
```

i am not getting how `val[i*c+j]` is working in this. Can anyone explain this to me.
i want to know how 2d array works dynamically and takes input from user and display it

Comment: `i*c+j` is a number. Run the loop on a piece of paper and see how that number varies with `i` and `j` if you need to.

Comment: Does it make more sense with more descriptive variable names? `val[row_number * num_columns + column_number]`

Comment: ohh i got it i was thinking of reference operator till now but after looping on paper i understood everything thanks @hobbs

Comment: You know you get garbage output right? Is this just to practice? It doesn't even run unless you move  `val = new int[r*c];` below the user inputs ..